# add 1 to your score in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map where you "capture" beacons (by placing stained glass on them) and your score should go up 1. So my question is: how do I add 1 to my scoreboard objective: `"beaconscaptured"`

I already know how to detect the block the command, so far is right here:

```
/execute @e[name=Beacon] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:stained_glass 0 `command`
```

What do I put in place of `command`?

Answer (score 2):

```
scoreboard players add @p beaconscaptured 1
```

You might want to have a look at the [command reference for the scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Command_reference), since those are very easy commands.

Comment: yeah scoreboard commands are my weakness XD

Answer (score 0):

The command you use in your answer is already wrong. You cannot use execute to test off blocks.

What you need to do is use in a repeating commandblock:

```
/testforblock <x> <z> <y> minecraft:stained_glass -1
```

Obviously replace `<x> <z> <y>` with the x,y and z of the block above the beacon, so the space where the glass would be placed. I also used '-1' instead '0' because a datavalue of 0 tests only for white colored stained glass, while -1 tests for all colors of stained glass. If you intented this replace -1 with 0 again.

And than run a chained conditional commandblock from that doing something like:

```
/scoreboard players add @p[x=<x>,y=<y>,z=<z>] BeaconsCaptured 1
```

In this case `<x> <z> <y>` are the coordinates of the beacon.

For this to work though you need to do this in chat once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add BeaconsCaptured dummy
```

This adds an objective called BeaconsCaptured that can only be updated trough commands (dummy).